# MonoDevelop can't resize main window

Tags: monodevelop

can anybody explain to me why is that MonoDevelop main window does not resize to bellow a lower width and height? Is this normal? Is it a bug?

PS: On mac, version 4.0.1

Comment: Whats the point of a screenshot, screenshot does not show the resizing not working. @knocte

Comment: add a screenshot of what's the minimum you can resize to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I - n00b with anger - had problems resizing the Main Window at all.

Here is how I managed to do so:
rightclick on mainwindow in designer-> Mainwindow -> Select

In the Properties Window:
Window Size Properties -> check "Resizable"
(even if it seems checked, check it again!)

Now I can resize the Windows as big or small as I want.

//Edit: I would also like to point out, that for most widgets there is a "Common widget Properties" region in the properties View. Have a look at "RequestWidth" and "RequestHeight" if youre used to .Net and looking for a way to resize Widget Controls.

Comment: Where is this "designer"?

Comment: Open the DefaultWindow.cs (or what its called) and have a look at the bottom of the code area. There you can "switch Tabs" from "Code" to "Design". (Took me a while to find it too)